# In a SOQL statement, what is the =: symbol?

Tags: soql

How does `=` differ from `=:` ?

My code snippet below only works when using `=:`, however when looking through the SOQL documentation, I mostly see examples using `=`.

```
public class AccountUtils {

    public static List<Account> accountsByState(String abbr) {
        list<Account> result = [SELECT ID, Name FROM Account WHERE BillingState =: abbr];
        system.debug(result);
        return result; 
    }
}
```

Versus an example from the documentation that uses `=`:

```
SELECT Id
FROM Case
WHERE Contact.LastName = null
```

Comment: Be sure to check [Salesforce Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_database/apex_database_soql) for basics on SOQL, Apex, etc.

Answer (score 6):

The `:` denotes a variable, in your case for `abbr` in your SOQL e.g.

```
SELECT ID, Name FROM Account WHERE BillingState = :abbr
```

as opposed to `null` which is a literal value

```
SELECT Id FROM Case WHERE Contact.LastName = null
```

in short if you are using a variable in SOQL then use `:` before the variable name.

Comment: Put in a slightly different way, there is no `=:` operator in SOQL, the equality "=" and bind ":" operators are two separate things.

Comment: `:` denotes a variable *or expression*. This bit is important. You can do, for example, `:System.today().addDays(5)` if you wanted to, or even `:Math.getRandomLong()`. Dynamic queries only support variables, but inline queries support both variables and expressions.

Comment: This makes sense, and thank you for the clarification on the bind operator!

Comment: Because they are two different operators, it should be _preferred_ that there is a space between the two, and that the bind operator touch the expression it is bound too: `WHERE Id IN :someSet`. This helps eliminate ambiguity in what the two operators are doing and makes it clear that, unlike the addition assignment operator `+=` or the less than or equal to operator `<=`, putting the two of them together does not make them work any differently.

Answer (score 2):

> SOQL and SOSL statements in Apex can reference Apex code variables and expressions if they’re preceded by a colon (:). This use of a local code variable within a SOQL or SOSL statement is called a bind. The Apex parser first evaluates the local variable in code context before executing the SOQL or SOSL statement. Bind expressions can be used as:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_variables.htm#!